# cakephp datasource Call to undefined method

Tags: php, cakephp

I've created a simple `datasource`:

```
// app/Model/Datasource/FeedSource.php

App::uses('DataSource', 'Model/Datasource');

class FeedSource extends DataSource {
    public function abcd() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

in my `database.php`:

```
public $feed = array(
    'datasource' => 'FeedSource'
);
```

And in `Feeda` model:

```
class Feeda extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false;
    public $useDbConfig = 'feed';
}
```

in `list` controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Feeda');
$this->Feeda->abcd();
```

But, it returns a fatal error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method FeedSource::query()
```

How to resolve it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant `DboSource` instead of `DataSource`.

DataSource has no method query, DboSource does. Update your code to look like:

```
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/Datasource');
class FeedSource extends DboSource {}
```

Edit: Looks like that is not the issue. In the `Model` there is a magic __call method which calls 
`$this->getDataSource()->query($method, $params, $this);` [Source](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html) You need to implement this yourself.

```
class FeedSource extends DataSource {
    public function abcd() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }

    public function query($method, $params, $Model) {
        // you may customize this to your needs.
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
    }
}
```