# CakePHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::findById()

Tags: php, cakephp, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cakephp datasource Call to undefined method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925523/cakephp-datasource-call-to-undefined-method)

I'm getting this kind of error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::findById() in C:\wamp\www\studiohelper\app\controllers\recurring_invoices_controller.php on line 309
```

Here is the code on that line:

```
$invoice = $this->Invoice->findById($invoiceId);
```

It looks like a pretty basic code but why on earth do I get that kind of error?

Comment: Where does `$this->Invoice` come from? We need to see more code.

Comment: That's how you call a model in CakePHP

Comment: Obviously you are missing something then.

Comment: Okay, I just solved it by adding this piece of code on top:
var $uses = array('RecurringInvoice','Invoice'); Sorry, noob here.

Comment: @tereško Possible duplicate? what?! You kidding me brothah!? hahaha!

Comment: Duplicate? There was no even proper answer that I see on the similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in your model name. Actually in cake php it is like this

```
$this->Modelname->findById($id);
```

Can you please check in your model that the model name is Invoice or RecurringInvoice please make sure this.